# Get WordPress plugin directory URI

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to include a WooCommerce file while running a plugin. Here is the code I am using,

```
include_once(include( content_url() .'/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php'));
```

This gives me below error,

```
 include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /nas/content/staging/squatwolf/wp-content/plugins/wpfront-notification-bar/classes/class-wpfront-notification-bar.php on line 58
```

I understand its being caused because the content_url function is giving complete url instead of relative url. I also tried,

```
plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)
```

but it gives the url of the plugin I am in, not the wordpress plugin directory url.

Comment: That error message suggests that URL including is turned off in your PHP configuration. It's needs turning back on.

Answer (score 0):

you want like this : `/home/user/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/`? 
try `$dir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ );`